# How to edit the 'Layout setup code' in the code customizer in netbeans

Tags: java, swing, netbeans

I am working on a java swing desktop application with NetBeans, I am trying to customize the layout of a panel by adding some custom components which can't be done by drag and drop in the NetBeans design view. After adding and sizing the panel in the design view, NetBeans generates the following code:

```
salesInfoPanel = new javax.swing.JPanel();
```

...
Some other stuff are generated here but they are too many to paste
...

```
salesInfoPanel.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(255, 255, 255));
        salesInfoPanel.setBorder(javax.swing.BorderFactory.createTitledBorder(null, "Sales Info", javax.swing.border.TitledBorder.DEFAULT_JUSTIFICATION, javax.swing.border.TitledBorder.DEFAULT_POSITION, new java.awt.Font("Adobe Caslon Pro", 0, 8))); // NOI18N
```

**Now this is the part I want to handcode myself**

```
        javax.swing.GroupLayout salesInfoPanelLayout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(salesInfoPanel);
        salesInfoPanel.setLayout(salesInfoPanelLayout);
        salesInfoPanelLayout.setHorizontalGroup(
            salesInfoPanelLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGap(0, 0, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        );
        salesInfoPanelLayout.setVerticalGroup(
            salesInfoPanelLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGap(0, 132, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        );
```

**End of layout code**

Now my problem is I have a method that does the custom layout and it adds the custom components to the layout in the panel. But this code cannot be integrated because NetBeans has already done layout above. I just want to be able to call the method before the panel is added into another panel and layout as done below by NetBeans:

```
javax.swing.GroupLayout invoicePanelLayout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(invoicePanel);
        invoicePanel.setLayout(invoicePanelLayout);
        invoicePanelLayout.setHorizontalGroup(
            invoicePanelLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(invoicePanelLayout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap()
                .addGroup(invoicePanelLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addGroup(invoicePanelLayout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addGap(0, 0, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                        .addComponent(advertLabel, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 209, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                        .addGap(32, 32, 32))
                    .addGroup(invoicePanelLayout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addComponent(invoiceNoLabel)
                        .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                        .addComponent(invoiceNoValue, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                        .addContainerGap())))
            .addGroup(invoicePanelLayout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGroup(invoicePanelLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addGroup(invoicePanelLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING, false)
                        .addComponent(salesInfoPanel,<-------//Here is the panel
javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                            .addComponent(customerInfoPanel, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                            .addComponent(cashInfoPanel, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                        .addGroup(invoicePanelLayout.createSequentialGroup()
                            .addContainerGap()
                            .addComponent(logoLabel)))
                    .addGap(0, 0, Short.MAX_VALUE))
            );
```

Sorry for the long code but I hope you understand what I mean thanks.